# Saving Color into Core Data for the iOS and macOS Apps

Tags: swift, core-data

I am building an app (SwiftUI) which will be used for iOS and macOS platform. One of the challenges, I am facing is storing Color (SwiftUI) into the database. In other apps I have used NSValueTransformer to use it with UIColor or NSColor but now the problem is that iOS and macOS share the codebase. I am using Core Data so the data model is being shared but the data saved is on separate SQLite files. If I want to sync the data to iCloud then would't I face issues if iOS app stored color as UIColor and macOS app stored color as NSColor?

How can I resolve this issue?

Comment: I'd look into storing the RGB (or equivalent) numerical values instead of trying to store a `Color`, `UIColor`, or `NSColor` -- that way it can be easily converted to any object representation.

Comment: Thanks I ended by storing the hex code. Thanks!

Answer (score -2):

import UIKit
import CoreData

class saveDataScreenViewController: UIViewController {

```
@IBOutlet weak var txtName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtId: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtUserName: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var txtPassword: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var btnSave: UIButton!

//MARK: - Create context for save data

let context = (UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate).persistentContainer.viewContext

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    
}

//MARK: - save button click with validation and saving data to core data

@IBAction func didTapSave(_ sender: UIButton) {
    
    if txtName.text!.isEmpty {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Please enter Name", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(okAction)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else if txtId.text!.isEmpty {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Please enter id", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(okAction)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else if txtUserName.text!.isEmpty {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Please enter username", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(okAction)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else if txtPassword.text!.isEmpty {
        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Alert", message: "Please enter password", preferredStyle: .alert)
        let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default, handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(okAction)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
    } else {
        let Entity = NSEntityDescription.insertNewObject(forEntityName: "EntityName", into: context)
        clinicEntity.setValue(txtName.text!, forKey: "Name")
        clinicEntity.setValue(txtId.text!, forKey: "id")
        clinicEntity.setValue(txtPassword.text!, forKey: "password")
        clinicEntity.setValue(txtUserName.text!, forKey: "username")
        
        do {
            try context.save()
            self.txtUserName.text = ""
            self.txtPassword.text = ""
            self.txtName.text = ""
            self.txtId.text = ""
            self.navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
        } catch {
            print("Error while insert data!")
        }
    }
    
}
```

}

Comment: How is this related to the question?

Comment: Can you provide a bit of supporting information for your code?